# android studio 4.0 unable to locate adb

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk

Actualice Android Studio a la version 4.0 y no puedo simular, pareciendo el mensaje :

> "unable to locate abd".

Revisé y todo parece estar en orden

Pueden ver en la imagen que tego instalado SDK Tools y Command-Line tools porque flutter doctor me dio problemas con este
[image: You can see I checked SDK Tools and Command-Line Tools because in flutter doctor had issues with the sdk manager]

El adb esta en la carpeta y la direccion la tengo en el antivirus para evitar falsos positivos
[image: Here you can see everything is in the foldier]

What's missing?

Comment: Un poco extraño , veo que tienes el proceso adb.exe dentro de  \Sdk\platform-tools, tienes un antivirus, podrìas revisar si adb.exe lo esta definiendo como una posible amenaza? Gracias por editar tu pregunta.

Comment: A decir es muy extraño la verdad pero te recomiendo que ocupes la herramienta de [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/toolbox/) de Jetbrains ya que las migraciones entre las versiones es muy fácil, yo pase de la 3.5 a la 4.0 sin ningun problema ya que todo lo gestiona la herramienta

Comment: Me paso eso el año pasado y cambie en ese momento la configuración del antivirus para establecer esa carpeta como segura. Metiéndome a Proyect Structure deje en SDK la ultima versión (la 28) y se resolvio pero ahora cada vez que inicio el simulador me dice que la version ADB es obsoleta, siendo que tengo la 30.0.0 y no aparece una nueva disponible. Luego la aplicacion se cierra indicacdo timeout de 15000 ms

Comment: Voy a revisar esa opción, muchas gracias